# Suppress list notation in Rmarkdown from lapply

Tags: r, r-markdown, lapply

I am using Rmarkdown to produce a report.  One of the steps includes a using lapply() with a function that produces a plot in order to produce multiple plots.  The function and lapply work well, but I get notation about which element in the list between each plot.

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)

#{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
myPlotFun <- function(z){
      diamonds %>%
            filter(color == !!z) %>%
            ggplot(aes(x= carat, y = price))+
            geom_point()
}
myList <- c("E","D","H")
lapply(myList, myPlotFun)
```

and I get:

'## [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvmCr.png)]

[image: plot1]
`##

`## [[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shKiX.png)]

[image: plot2]

How do I hide the list notation (e.g. ## [[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shKiX.png)]) lines in between the plots?
using include = FALSE hides both the plots and the list notation, which is not what I want.  I tried warning = FALSE, but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These numbers are artifacts from `lapply`. The easiest way to remove them is to use a `for` loop instead. Otherwise you could create a hook that removes any other output but plots:

````
```{r}
def <- knitr::knit_hooks$get("output")
knitr::knit_hooks$set(output = function(x, options) {
  x <- def(x, options)
  ifelse(!is.null(options$suppress), gsub(pattern = "```.*```", "", x), x)
})
```
````

Just set `suppress = T` for the relevant chunks.

Comment: This worked well, but how do I control when this is affecting the output?  It seems like it is affecting all subsequent chunks, how would I turn this feature off so I could, for example include a table as output in the report? Thanks

Comment: I assumed you will get back at me :P I'll update it.

Comment: Works great with the modification.  Thank you